# Django rest framework recieve POST values add new value > Save > Return response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The only solution i've found and since is POST that I'm sending i used the following on views.py please correct me if there is a proper way to do this but using request.DATA because when it passes on serializers.is_valid() goes true even if i send a empty post it always makes a new sessionid instead of validating it before. I've tried doing it with pre_save() but i don't know how it works and documentation seems like blackmagic for me.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def startCall(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    API_KEY = '00000'
    API_SECRET = '000000000000000'
    OTSDK = OpenTokSDK.OpenTokSDK(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    opentok_session = str(OTSDK.create_session().session_id)

    post_values = request.POST.copy()
    post_values['opentok_sessionid'] = str(opentok_session)

    serializer = startCallSerializer(data=post_values)

    if serializer.is_valid():

        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    else:

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class startCallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = call
    fields = ('tutor', 'billed')
    exclude = ('tutor','billed')
```

Comment: It doesn't get answered because it's not a question.  It's a list and some code

Comment: The code above works, but i dont even know where to start that's why i  posted the list because i got no clue where to put things together.

Comment: @skzryzg changed my question description, hope its better explained now. :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to do some client-side data validation to check if there is relevant text in the text-area. You must try to understand the principles of GET/POST to make this work. POSTING something and making it return a response isn't a good way to go about achieving what you want to achieve. What you must instead do is use GET after POST. As soon as the data is posted, it should be available for the GET request to fetch the data.

Comment: i did this.     payload = request.DATA.copy()
    payload.update({'opentok_sessionid': opentok_session })
    serializer = startCallSerializer(data=payload)

and added the opentok_sessionid but its not saving tutor and billed IDs

Comment: What i want to do is generate a call session so to do that i need to save on the database tutor and billed but since the person who makes the call does not generate the opentok_session i do it before it gets saved on the database and then pass 3 values to the serializer to get it saved. so i end up saving 3 values (tutor, billed, opentok_sessionid) and then after its saved i only show the opentok_sessionid to the user as a response. 
POST tutor,billed  SAVE  tutor,billed, opentok_sessionid and then 
RESPONSE [{ 'opentok_sessionid':'234234234324'}]